# Transferring video from a camera to an OPENCV c++ client

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. My task is to write a client-server program that will record video to a buffer until the client connects to the camera, and then transfer this buffer with video to him via TCP IP, I wrote the code, but it transmits only 1 frame. I need to somehow determine the size of the array or change the transmission algorithm (now it is implemented using the SEND function).
I'm sorry for my English.

Server(on a video camera):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int c,new_socket;
std::vector<uchar> arrak;
int main()
{
    int sock,listener;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;
    std::vector<int> params(2);
    params[0] = cv::IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION;
    params[1] = 10;
    struct sockaddr_in addr,client;


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);// подключение по сокету
    if(sock < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);// подключается к любому ip

     if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) { // связывание сокетов
        perror("[server] binding faild!");
        exit(2);
    }
     Mat frame;
     int bbytee;
     int imgSize = frame.total() * frame.elemSize();
    // int imgSize = frame.cols*frame.rows*3; // узнаем размер изображения на три канала
     frame = Mat::zeros(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3); // заполнение нулями массива frame
listen(sock, 1); // прослушивание подключений
while (true){
     c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // размер структуры
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
new_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*)&c);
if(new_socket==-1) //принятие подключения и создания по него нового сокета
     {
         puts("Connection NO NO NO NO  accepted");
         cout << "new_socket = " << new_socket << "\n";


    cout << "before open the cam" << endl;
    cout << "IDET ZAPIS!" << endl;
    VideoCapture cap(2); // захват видеокамеры

    if(!cap.isOpened()) { // проверка условий подключения
        cout<< "Could not open the camera" <<  endl;
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }


    int cnt=0;

        cap >> frame;// передача кадра с cap в frame

        /*if (frame.isContinuous()) {
          // array.assign(mat.datastart, mat.dataend); // <- has problems for sub-matrix like mat = big_mat.row(i)
          arrak.assign(frame.data, frame.data + frame.total()*frame.channels());
        } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; ++i) {
            arrak.insert(arrak.end(), frame.ptr<uchar>(i), frame.ptr<uchar>(i)+frame.cols*frame.channels());
          }
        }
        cout<<"VECTOR: "<<arrak[1]<<endl;
*/
        if(frame.empty()) {
            cerr<<"[client] VideoCapture(0) error!"<<endl;
        }

        cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buf, params);
        cout<< ++cnt << ":"<< frame.isContinuous()<<"," <<frame.size()<<endl;;

    }
else {
    while (true){
        int p=sizeof(frame)/sizeof(frame.data[0]);
        printf("BUFF 1: %d\n",buf[1]);
        printf("BUFF 2: %d\n",buf[2]);
        break;
        //cout <<"CONNECT ! CONNECT ! CONNECT !";
        cout << " Frame size : "<<frame.size()<<endl;
        if( (bbytee = send(new_socket, frame.data, imgSize, 0)) ==-1) {//передача данных в сокет
                        cerr<< "bytes = " << bbytee << endl;
                        break;
                    }
    }
    break;
}
}
cout<< "KONESSSSSSSSSS "<<endl;
if (frame.isContinuous()) {
         // array.assign(mat.datastart, mat.dataend); // <- has problems for sub-matrix like mat = big_mat.row(i)
         arrak.assign(frame.data, frame.data + frame.total()*frame.channels());
       } else {
         for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; ++i) {
           arrak.insert(arrak.end(), frame.ptr<uchar>(i), frame.ptr<uchar>(i)+frame.cols*frame.channels());
         }
       }
       cout<<"VECTOR: "<<arrak[1]<<endl;
cout <<"END"<<endl;
    close(sock);//закрытие сокета
    return 0;
}
```

Client(on PC):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

 
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//открытие сокета
    if(sock < 0){//проверка на открытие
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
        }

    memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.3.11");// указано IP платы 

 if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){//подключение к плате
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }




while(true){
    int num_of_recv_bytes;
    VideoWriter outputVideo;
    Size S = Size((int) 1920,(int) 1080);
    outputVideo.open("receive.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('H','2','6','4'), 25, S, true);

    int imgSize = 1080*1920*3;
    Mat frame = Mat::zeros(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3);//заполнение нулями
    uchar *iptr = frame.data;
    int key;

    int cnt=0;
    while(1){
        cout << ++cnt<<endl;
       
        while(key != 'q') {
            if( num_of_recv_bytes = recv(sock, iptr, imgSize, MSG_WAITALL) == -1 ) {// чтение данных из сокета
                cerr << "recv failed, received bytes = " << num_of_recv_bytes << endl;
            }

            outputVideo<< frame;
            if (key = waitKey(100) >= 0) break;
        }
        outputVideo.release();
        close(sock);// закрытие сокета
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

I wrote software, but it transmits only 1 frame, I need to change the algorithm or add a function so that it transmits all the frames accumulated before connecting the client.

Comment: You should organize your code, it looks so messy right now. Maybe segregate communication and OpenCV processing into separate classes.

Comment: Also, `if (key = waitKey(100) >= 0)` this line should be `if ((key = waitKey(100)) >= 0)`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but thanks

Comment: That can be a serious issue actually, better to fix it right away.